# Redirecting Firefox to a Proxy on Localhost

Tags: c, http, firefox, proxy

For class, I have to write a basic proxy server in C.

I need to test it with firefox, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Say I have the server listening on port X-- how do I make firefox (on the same computer) send its requests there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the proxy that Firefox uses in the Advanced > Network > Connection dialogue. You will almost certainly want to set your proxy (host localhost, port X) as an HTTP proxy. (The first box, labelled "HTTP proxy", takes the hostname, the second, labelled "port", the port.)

Comment: For the box that says "HTTP Proxy", what information does it want? the port number goes in the next box over...

Comment: It wants the hostname, ie localhost.

Answer (score 7):

To enable sending localhost traffic to a proxy in recent versions of Firefox, open `about:config`, search for "localhost", and set `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` to true.

This is in Firefox 71, and apparently was added around 67.  Ran into it while trying to use Fiddler.

Answer (score 2):

Simply set HTTP Proxy in Advanced > Network > Connection to 127.0.0.1 and port "X".